# Neo4j - Cypher read-write-return query

Tags: python, node.js, neo4j, read-write, cypher

I'm fairly new to neo4j. I've played a little bit with cypher and REST API. I want to be able to create a leaf node along certain path, consider these nodes are some types of events. I wouldn't know during run time the id of the node this event will be attached to. I need to either do a look-up and then get the id of the node and then create my new node.

So during run time I was hoping I can do a MATCH using cypher to get the node to which I can attach the event and CREATE new node along with the relationship to the existing node returned by MATCH. So I came across the cypher cheat sheet which has a read-write-return query which I thought would be good fit. But there is nothing much mentioned about it in documentation or may be I'm not a super googler!!

Could someone please tell me if this(read-write-return) is the right/valid approach?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yep. That's a good approach. That's one of the nice things about how `CREATE` works in Cypher. You can also optionally use `create unique` which creates the rel/node at the same time. Something like:

```
start n=node(1)
create unique n-[:event]->(event {prop:"val"})
return n, event;
```

Or without `create unique`:

```
start n=node(1)
create (event {prop:"val"}), n-[:event]->event
return n, event;
```

Comment: Thanks - may be I should have been clearer in the question. In both the examples above you are starting at node id 1, and then creating a node with the relationship ":event" to node(1), I want something like,
`START client=node:node_auto_index(client_name="Client1")
MATCH client-[:OWNS]->(device1)
create (event {time: "1234567890"}), device1-[:FAILURE_EVENT]->event
return device, event`
Is this possible? I haven't tried the above query myself. Cheers

Comment: Yep, it will work, but device1 will match all of the devices that client :OWNS, which might not be what you want?

Comment: Good catch - no I would like to get a unique device which might have been created already. do I do a `WHERE` then and then `CREATE`? I'm trying to avoid the lookup to INSERT/UPDATE. Something along the lines of upsert in mongodb would be cool. But I'm not sure how to achieve it in neo4j. Many Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you can do `CREATE` and `WHERE` together, and you can also use `CREATE UNIQUE`, which will actually check the properties (eg. device_id or something) before creating the new node. Try it out in console.neo4j.org (which you can share via a link). If you describe your exact starting scenarios and the end that you want, maybe we can come up with a good cypher query for you.